# No signature of method: with flutter

Tags: android, flutter

can anyone help solve this problem?

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

- Where:
  Build file 'USER' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
  No signature of method: build_5m3vrzqpuwf7ewlzf5pa3dgnt.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_5m3vrzqpuwf7ewlzf5pa3dgnt$_run_closure2) values: [build_5m3vrzqpuwf7ewlzf5pa3dgnt$_run_closure2@3ae9eb62]

  ```
   def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }

    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }

    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

    android {
        compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }

        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }

        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.huseyiincavus.ourchat"
            // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
            // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
            minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }

    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.2')
    }
  ```

Comment: probably has something to do with these lines. try changing to maybe 30 or 31 for compileversion and 26 for minversion to see whether error resolve:

    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion